# STL iterable container like priority_queue

Tags: c++, stl, containers, priority-queue

I'm new to STL containers (and C++ in general) so thought I would reach out to the community for help. I basically want to have a `priority_queue` that supports constant iteration. Now, it seems that `std::priority_queue` doesn't support iteration, so I'm going to have to use something else, but I'm not sure exactly what.

Requirements:

- Maintains order on insertion (like a priority queue)
- Pop from top of list
- Get const access to each element of the list (don't care about the order in the queue for this stage)

One option would be to keep a `priority_queue` and separately have an `unordered_set` of references, but I'd rather not have two containers floating around. I could also use a `deque` and search through for the right insertion position, but I'd rather have the container manage the sorting for me if possible (and constant-time insertion would be nicer than linear-time). Any suggestions?

Comment: Quick note -- inserting into a priority queue takes log time, not constant.  Also, it isn't sorting the queue.  It's just keeping the least element on top.

Comment: Good to know. I guess I made some (false) assumptions about the internal implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a std::vector might be enough as others already pointed, but if you want already-ready implementation, maybe use Boost.Heap (which is a library with several priority queue containers): http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/heap.html

Boost is a collection of libraries that basically complete the standard library (which is not really big). A lot of C++ developers have boost ready on their dev computer to use it when needed. Just be careful in your choices of libraries.

Comment: Nice, didn't know about those. We're already using Boost for this project so I'll take a look. I've been having trouble getting Boost containers to compile for the TS-7800, though, so if that fails I'll have to try a different option.

Answer (score 3):

There are two options that come to mind:

1) Implement your own iterable priority queue, using `std::vector` and the heap operation algorithms (see **Heap Operations** [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm)).

2) derive (privately) from `priority_queue`. This gives you access to the underlying container via data member `c`. You can then expose iteration, random access, and other methods of interest in your public interface.

Comment: 2) I've seen that suggestion around, and was thinking about it, but I'm wary about deriving from existing containers. Certainly an option, though.

Comment: @chessbot I share your misgivings, but private inheritance is reasonably safe (not fool-proof though).

Answer (score 1):

You can use (ordered) set as a queue. set.begin() will be your top element, and you can pop it via erase(set.begin()).

Comment: This is not what the OP is looking for.  They want a heap implementation.  `std::set` is most likely not implemented as a heap.

Comment: I have a Java background, and the idea of Set being ordered just sounds wrong to me (I was looking for a SortedSet and didn't find one; guess that's why there is `unordered_set`.

Comment: @paddy The word "heap" doesn't appear in OP question, he wants priority queue and set supports all functionality needed.

Comment: @paddy True, though I strictly don't need one since this is likely not a high-volume container.

Comment: @chessbot c++ set (just set, from header <set>) is sorted, see: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/.

Comment: @KimStrauss Yep, I saw that; just didn't think to look there first!

Answer (score 1):

Have you observed heap ([std::make_heap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/make_heap/)) ? It hasn't order inside of queue, but has priority "pop from top of list" which you need.